# VBA Passing cells/range of cells to multiple subs

Tags: vba, excel

Hi i have a problem defining a range of cells as a variable depending on what group of cells have changed. So far I have this but it sends up multiple errors, I have tried passing them as string and creating temp variables to hold the values and pass that but no matter what it does not seem to work.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not (Application.Intersect(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:E"), Target) Is Nothing) Then
    DoSort("A3:F100", "A4")
End If
If Not (Application.Intersect(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H:L"), Target) Is Nothing) Then
    DoSort("H3:M100", "H4)
End If
End Sub

Sub DoSort(x As Range, y As Range)
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
.Range(x).Sort Key1:=.Range(y), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With
End Sub
```

I had it working before when i hard coded the cells in like this:

```
Private Sub DoSort2()
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
.Range("H3:M100").Sort Key1:=.Range("H4"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With
End Sub
```

Never really worked in VBA with excel macros so am very new to this, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my refactored code below. See my comments for explanation.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'I used "Me." in place of "Worksheets("Sheet1")." assuming that the Worksheet_Change event is already on Sheet1    
    If Not Intersect(Me.Range("A:E"), Target) Is Nothing Then
         DoSort "A3:F100", "A4"
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Me.Range("H:L"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        DoSort "H3:M100", "H4"  'you were missing a close " here
    End If

End Sub

'define x and y as String to pass the string address of the range reference
Sub DoSort(x As String, y As String)
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range(x).Sort Key1:=.Range(y), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    End With
End Sub
```

You could pass the range if you want as well. That would look like this:

```
   DoSort Me.Range("A3:F100"), Me.Range("A4")

   Sub DoSort(x as Range, y as Range)
      x.Sort Key1:=y, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
   End Sub
```

Comment: Smart using the Me pointer (will have to remeber that), and I get somehow get a syntax error from the code now. Is there something I am missing? Also do I have to define x and y in the sub as they are already declared when be passed the reference?

Comment: @Phoenix1237 - what line does the syntax error occur on? And no need to define `x` or `y` in the `DoSort` sub. The argument reference does that already.

Comment: the error occurs on Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range), but the macro is stored within Sheet1.

Comment: @Phoenix1237 - I think it was the unnecessary parenthesis in the `DoSort` call. Try now. You can check simply by compiling the code.

Comment: Yes that was it! I guess my Java habits leaked through, thank  you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the data as a String versus as a Range:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:E"), Target) Is Nothing) Then
        DoSort("A3:F100", "A4")
    End If
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H:L"), Target) Is Nothing) Then
        DoSort("H3:M100", "H4")
    End If
End Sub

Sub DoSort(x As String, y As String)
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range(x).Sort Key1:=.Range(y), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes I tried this but I somehow get a syntax error when I attempt to test.

Comment: It points to Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Comment: @Phoenix1237 Where is that macro stored?

Comment: It is stored within Sheet1 which is why I am confused why it would be an issue.